# "Attempt to call a nil value" with data stores

Tags: lua, save, roblox

I called the moduleScript and I did everything correctly I think
I also tried with a normal script but it didnt work
Pls help I tried lots of things but nothing works Im creating a new game and I cant continue the game because the data doesnt save
Im putting so much text because if not I cant publish this :)

```
local PlayerStatManager = {}

local DataStoreService = game:GetService("DataStoreService")
local playerData = DataStoreService:GetChildren("DataPlayer")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    local stats =   Instance.new("Folder")
    stats.Parent = player
    stats.Name = "leaderstats"
    
    local clicks = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    clicks.Name = "Clicks"
    clicks.Parent = stats
    
    local coins = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    coins.Name = "Coins"
    coins.Parent = stats
    
    local rebirths = Instance.new("NumberValue")
    rebirths.Name = "Rebirths"
    rebirths.Parent = stats
    
    local id = player.UserId
    clicks.Value = playerData:GetAsync(player.UserId)
    
end)

game.Players.PlayerRemoving:Connect(function(player)
    local id = player.UserId
    playerData:SetAsync(id, player.leaderstats.Clicks.Value)
end)

return PlayerStatManager
```

Comment: The full error message would be helpful

Comment: I don't know anything about programming for roblox  but I notice that your first function does nothing but create a bunch of local variables and then does nothing with it. No wonder nothing really happens.

Comment: you're calling a nil value. that error message is quite clear. that error message usually comes with a line number so it is quite easy to find out which nil value you're attempting to call. make sure it is not nil befor you call it

Answer (score 1):

```lua
local playerData = DataStoreService:GetChildren("DataPlayer")
```

This line causes the problem.

First of all, `GetChildren` doesn't get a child of an instance, it returns an array-like table of all children. In that case, `FindFirstChild` makes more sense.

Well, even `FindFirstChild` isn't correct! `DataStoreService` shouldn't have any children - if it does, you shouldn't care about them. You probably wanted to use [GetDataStore](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/DataStoreService/GetDataStore).

About the error message, it says that you're trying to call a nil value, which means that you're trying to call something that doesn't exist. It's this line that causes the error:

```lua
clicks.Value = playerData:GetAsync(player.UserId)
```

You are using `GetChildren`, which returns a table. `playerData` is a table. You're trying to get `GetAsync` and then call it. In the table, we don't have the key `GetAsync` (we only have number keys, because it's an array-like table). So you're trying to call a `nil` value.